# generating references to <li>

Tags: css, xml, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file that I transform with XSLT 2.0 into xhtml. The file has a line like this:

```
<p>Here I refer to list item number (<lat:listref href="nr"/>) below to tell you about.....</p>
```

and elsewhere, nested in other elements in that same file a numbered (in CSS) list:

```
<ol>
  <li>list item 1</i>
  <li>list item 2</i>
  <li><span id="nr">list</span> item 3</i>
</ol>
```

`<lat:listref href="nr"/>` must be transformed into the number 3.

So far I came up with:

```
<xsl:template match="lat:listref">
    <xsl:variable name="l" select="@href"/>
    <xsl:number select="//li[*//@id=$l]"  level="single"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Can I do this without the need of a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a key: `<xsl:key name="k1" match="ol/li/span[@id]" use="@id"/>`.

Then in your template for the `lat:listref` simply do `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', @href)/parent::li" mode="m1"/>`.

Finally write a template: `<xsl:template match="ol/li" mode="m1"><xsl:number/></xsl:template>`

Comment: Thanks. And if the id'd element (here span) can be any element at any level nested within the li, I use ancestor::, I presume, and "ol/li/*[@id]" in the xsl:key. Can I use xsl:number's "value" attribute to start outputting numbers at, say, 100?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use [current() as defined by the XSLT 2.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-function):

```
<xsl:template match="lat:listref">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(//li[.//@id = current()/@href]/preceding-sibling::li) + 1"/>
</xsl:template>
```